# How to log events in freeze time?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, logging

My computer freeze randomly on `win7-32bit` and I'm sure about this is a hardware issue.
I can't find any solve for this problem. So I decided to find problem by myself.
Now I'm trying to find something to understand problem.

Comment: Is there any pattern about when it freezes (such as video, music, internet activity etc)? Did you make sure all your drivers are up to to date? Does the event log have any detail?

Comment: event log don't have anything.and as I said this is totaly hardware issue.my drivers are up to date.sometimes it freezes on starting windows animation or even on bios page and there is no pattern.

Comment: And I assume it never creates a BSOD or restart?

Comment: no.if freeze is on motherboard screen(where shows f keys for menus) it restarts otherwise even on bios it just freeze.

Comment: @DaveRook as I said there is no reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
problem is the `SATA` cable of my HDD.I tested a new sata cable and there is no freeze anymore.

Answer (score 1):

*Typically* hardware works or fails although I do agree, it does sound like hardware.

The fact the BIOS fails (as per your comments in the OP) rules out (IMO) the hard drive, leaving graphics, CPU and RAM. I would suggest using just 1 stick of RAM for a while to see if that has any effect (and if it does freeze, change the RAM stick until you've proven the same issue occurs with all the RAM sticks).

You also have the option to use software. I think you'll need to test each part separately if possible

Test the memory chips, using Memtest86

Test the CPU and board using Hot CPU Tester

If they come back clean, then maybe try using a different graphic unit?

I would still consider running a SMART tool on the hard drive.

Comment: something might help to find problem.if there is a music playing it plays until end(or on start of loop). also sometimes it lags one second before freeze.witch is exactly why I searching for a logger software.

Comment: When it freezes, what happens if you press capslock on your keyboard? Does the LED turn on and off?

Comment: yeah capslock works.also sometimes the harddrive LED(it means r/w on hard drive) is blinking in freeze state.and if a usb stick is connected before, It's LED is blinking too.

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions in my post?